# Laravel-Vuex:Update to a record not showing in the database

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to update a record in laravel-vue project using vuex and i cant get to push the changes to the database,my dd($request->all())returns a null,i tested my api using postman and the update function is working well
This is my actions code:
`

```
updateCategory({ commit }, updatedCategory) {
        axios.put("api/food_categories/" + updatedCategory.id).then(() => {
            commit("changeName", updatedCategory);
        });
```

`mutations code:`

```
 changeName(state,updatedCategory){
         const index = state.food_categories.findIndex(
            food_category => food_category.id === updatedCategory.id
        );
        if (index !== -1) {
            state.food_categories.splice(index, 1, updatedCategory);
        }  
    },
```

update function:`

```
updCategory() {
                const categoryDetails = {
                    id: this.form.id,
                    category_name: this.form.category_name
                };
                this.updateCategory(categoryDetails);
                console.log(categoryDetails);
                this.form = "";
            },
```

`
Component:

```
` 

<b-form
                                    @submit.prevent="
                                        editMode ? updCategory() : onSubmit()
                                    "
                                    @reset="onReset()"
                                    v-if="show"
                                >
                                    <b-form-group
                                        id="input-group-1"
                                        label="Category Name:"
                                        label-for="input-1"
                                        description="Category Name."
                                    >
                                        <b-form-input
                                            id="input-1"
                                            v-model="form.category_name"
                                            type="text"
                                            required
                                            placeholder="Enter Category Name"
                                        ></b-form-input>
                                    </b-form-group>

                                    <b-button
                                        type="submit"
                                        v-show="!editMode"
                                        variant="success"
                                        class="float-right"
                                        >Submit</b-button
                                    >
                                    <b-button
                                        type="submit"
                                        v-show="editMode"
                                        variant="primary"
                                        class="float-right"
                                        >Update</b-button
                                    >
                                </b-form>`
```

My controller:`

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
          $food_category=FoodCategory::findOrFail($id);
         $food_category-> update($request->all());
       //dd($food_category);
    }
```

`

My problem is i dont get any error when i update but it just does not reflect reflect on my database and my request is empty.what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,i accidentally failed to pass the payload to the request as follows

```
  updateCategory({ commit }, updatedCategory) {
    axios.put("api/food_categories/" + updatedCategory.id,{
        'category_name':updatedCategory.category_name  //This was the missing part
    }).then(() => {
        commit("changeName", updatedCategory);
    });
},
```